# Using Google Cloud Messaging on iOS. "content_available" generates InternalServerError

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

According to the GCM reference document, the field "content_available" in the message to the client device is described as:

> *On iOS, use this field to represent content-available in the APNS payload. When a notification or message is sent and this is set to
>   true, an inactive client app is awoken. On Android, data messages wake
>   the app by default.*

However, when I specify this field, I get **InternalServerError** response from the GCM server.

Anyone able to shed any light on this? Is there a different way to wake up the application on iOS?

Comment: Can you share an example message that you're trying to send? The `content_available` field should be outside of the `notifications` field to begin with.

Comment: {
    "to":"npsrwibueG4:APA.....",
    "content_available" : true,
    "data" : {
    "message" : "Test Message",
    "action" : "display",
    "title" : "Alert from VMware",
    "deviceType" : "IOS"
    }
}

Comment: If I don't add the "content_available" in the above, the message gets through but doesn't wake up the IOS app.

Comment: I also tried the "notification" format in a PHP script:

{"multicast_id":6616349015156173043,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InternalServerError"}]}

Comment: This mostly seems like a issue with your APNS certs and their configuration. Your message with `{ "to":"..", "content_available" : true, "data" : { "message" : .. } }` goes via `APNS` but if you remove the `content_available` flag it goes through GCM's connection which is only there when the app is in the foreground. 

If you send this `{ "to":"..", "notification" : { "body" : .. }, "data": { "custom_data": .. }` this will also go through APNS and would most probably give you Internal Server Error. Try checking your certs at https://developers.google.com/mobile/add and make sure they are valid

Comment: Yes, specifying certs for *both* development mode and production mode seems to have solved the problem. Too bad the error isn't more descriptive - would have saved me many hours.